# When does $\left|z\right|e^{i\text{Arg}(z)}=z$ hold?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\text{Arg}(z):\mathbb{C}\to(-\pi,\pi]$ be the argument function. Find all the values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\left|z\right|e^{i\text{Arg}(z)}=z$.

My initial intuition was that the above is true for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$; However something tells me that might not be true, since that would make the original question I had to use this identity for much easier. Nevertheless, I could not figure out which values would be problematic.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried expressing $z=re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yeah. For the left side I get $|z|=r$ and $\text{Arg}(z)=\theta$, so eventually $re^{i\theta}$ is the left side, which is equal to the right, without any limitations (that's of course if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: You are correct. WolframAlpha [confirms it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+z%3D%7Cz%7C*exp%28i*Arg%28z%29%29).

Comment: What about $0$? What is $\arg$ then?

Comment: @Conrad I think that would be a matter of convention. I would say that it's $0$, others can say it's undefined, but I think as long as $|z|=0$ (since $z=0$) zero won't be a problem

Comment: Am ok with that